# How do I use SplitLayoutPanel with UIBinder?

Tags: java, xml, gwt, uibinder

How do I use SplitLayoutPanel with UIBinder? I've tried so many different things but none of them work properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll find that `SplitLayoutPanel` works just like `DockLayoutPanel`. (`SplitLayoutPanel` is a subclass of `DockLayoutPanel`.) You may have already read about this in the Developer's Guide section on [Layout Panels](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html#LayoutPanels).

Often, the UiBinder documentation for a class is actually given in the docs for its superclass. Take a look at the [documentation for `DockLayoutPanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DockLayoutPanel.html) and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

[The "Moving to Standards Mode" section](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html#Standards)  of the Developer's Guide page on Layout using Panels says "SplitPanels are very unpredictable in standards mode, and you should almost invariably replace them with SplitLayoutPanel."

If that doesn't solve your issue, then please be more specific as to something that you've tried, what you expected to happen, and what happened instead.

Comment: Ok then, how do I use a SplitLayoutPanel with UIBinder? I still cannot find any documentation containing sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code for SplitLayoutPanel,

```
<g:SplitLayoutPanel>
    <g:west size="200">
        <g:VerticalPanel />
    </g:west>
    <g:center>
        <g:VerticalPanel />
    </g:center>
    <g:south size="200">
        <g:VerticalPanel />
    </g:south>
    <g:north size="200">
        <g:VerticalPanel />
    </g:north>
</g:SplitLayoutPanel>
```

Thanks,

Gnik